# Add-ins not working for others users as they are not logged into Word application with the organization

Tags: ms-word, office365, ms-office, office-addins

I am using centralized deployment to deploy my add-ins to users but it is not working if any user has not logged into desktop word application with the organization email, I want that external users can also use my add-ins that are not in the organization. Is there any way I can do that with Centralized deployment? I tried to do organization log-in in word application as a different user but organization login was not possible it seems, but as an admin as I am already logged into word application I am able to get the add-ins.

Comment: Are these COM add-ins or Template Add-Ins? My general (non IT) advice has long been to have template Add-Ins sourced from the network storage but stored locally on the user's computer. They should be updated with the network login.

Comment: These are COM add-ins